# Get all eloquent models without relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to fetch all models that don't have a relationship.

Similar to fetching models which have one:

```
return $this->model->has('quote')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

I would basically like to have the inverse of this. I can't find any documentation to do this though.

Basically this query:

```
SELECT * FROM custom_design_requests
RIGHT JOIN quotes
ON quotes.`custom_design_request_id` = `custom_design_requests`.id
```

But I'd like to avoid having to use the Query Builder (`DB::table('custom_design_requests')->rightJoin('quotes', 'quotes.custom_design_request_id', '=', 'custom_design_requests.id')->get();`), so that I have a collection of instances of the model.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
$this->model->has('quote', '<', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick, should have though of this. :)

Comment: While the has() method seems very simple to use, you should keep in mind what Eloquent does internally when you call it. The resulting query will run a subselect for each record you have in your database which might not be efficient if you have a lot of data. In the case above the resulting SQL would be something like: SELECT * FROM models WHERE  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes WHERE model_id = models.id) < 1"

Answer (score 17):

I believe this is better than the accepted solution:

```
$this->model->doesntHave('quote')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This is described in more detail here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
return $this->model
  ->leftJoin('quotes', 'quotes.custom_design_request_id', '=', 'custom_design_requests.id')
  ->whereNull('quotes.custom_design_request_id')
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This will **LEFT JOIN** your model with quotes and take only those, for which there are no corresponding quotes.

Comment: Thank you, this works as well. I do prefer the `has('quote', '<', 1)` method. :)

Comment: Cool, i didn't know you can do it like that, I guess I learnt sth new today as well :)

Comment: left join is the more efficient way, I would definitely do it like this for large data sets.